# Compiler error with template classes, inheritance, and pointers-to-member-functions

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, pointer-to-member

```
class A{

    virtual int foo1(int a){ 

        return foo1_1(a,filler(a));
    }   

    template<typename FunctionPtr_filler> 
    int foo1_1(int a, FunctionPtr_filler ptrFn)
    {   
        int b;
        b = (this->*ptrFn)(a);  // --> compile error: pointer to member type int (B::)(int) incompatible with object type A
        return b;
    }   

    protected:
    virtual int filler(int a){ 
        return a*a;
    }   
};

class B: public A{
    virtual int foo1(int a){ 
        return foo1_1(a, &B::filler);
    }   
    virtual int filler(int a){ 
        return (a+a);
    }   
};
```

Is their any way to overcome this error. I want to pass the filler function and avoid the code smell of duplicate code.

Comment: I like how the first instinct of everybody is oh god, must fix formatting.

Comment: Well, this was a particularly bad one -- there were double quotes around the `<>` to deal with HTML "escaping"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you are passing as a parameter the following:

```
&B::filler
```

This is a pointer-to-member-function of a function defined in `B`.  In the base class, you are trying to call it as

```
(this->*ptrFn)(a);
```

The problem here is that if the receiver object isn't actually an object of type `B`, this would cause a serious runtime error, because you'd be calling a method in `B` on an object whose type wasn't `B`.  C++ is giving you a compiler error to tell you that this is not allowed.

To fix this, change the call to pass in

```
&A::filler
```

This is a method in `A`, so any `A` object will have this particular method.  C++ will automatically resolve the call virtually to refer to the most derived implementation of that method, so it should call the `B` version of the function in this case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If he passes `&A::filler`, then I don't think it will call invoke `B::filler`, which probably he wanted to invoke from the function template.

Comment: @Nawaz- My understanding is that calling a virtual member function through a pointer-to-member-function will do the normal virtual dispatch if it's done through a pointer.  Let me go check that...

Comment: I don't think so. The address of `A::filler` is different from `B::filler`. What you're suggesting is basically hardcoding the address of `A::filler`. The compiler will not replace with the address of `B::filler` (or `C::filler` if `this` refers to `C` object).

Comment: @Nawaz- Pointers to members in C++ are not just raw pointers to addresses; they contain extra information to allow this to work.  I remember I was doing some work on the g++ internals and was utterly baffled at first by what was going on, but when I realized it supports virtual dispatch everything suddenly made sense.

Comment: Incredible. I'm also baffled, [totally surprised](http://ideone.com/7VnBP). Still thinking how it works!... +1 BTW. :-)

Comment: Thanks, On having it protected it throws the following error 
>prog.cpp: In member function ‘virtual int B::foo1(int)’:
>prog.cpp:19: error: ‘virtual int A::filler(int)’ is protected
>prog.cpp:26: error: within this context

Comment: @Saaras- So looking over this, I'm starting to think that you have massively overcomplicated things.  If your `filter` function is virtual and protected, why not just directly call it in the base class implementation?  That will automatically resolve the call to the most derived version of the class.  There's no reason to add the extra pointer indirection in here.